# Angular 2 - Service method is called when navigating to child components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

When navigating between Account and Profile, the PeopleService is being called each time. You can also see the person's name and website details flicker.

Because the Account and Profile are children of PeopleComponent, and PeopleModule is the provider for the PeopleService, I'm expecting that the PeopleService to only be called when I first navigate to a Person, and for the person's details (name/website) not have to refresh (no flicker)

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFEYYN45o1LaLsIpJwSK

**PeopleModule:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PeopleService } from './people.service';

import { PeopleComponent } from './people.component';

import { peopleRouting } from './people.routes';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        peopleRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        PeopleComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        PeopleService
    ]
})
export class PeopleModule { }
```

**PeopleRoutes:**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PeopleComponent } from './people.component';

const peopleRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: PeopleComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'account',
                loadChildren: 'app/accounts/accounts.module#AccountsModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                loadChildren: 'app/profiles/profiles.module#ProfilesModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const peopleRouting = RouterModule.forChild(peopleRoutes);
```

**PeopleService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {

    constructor(
      private _http: Http
    ) { }


    get(id: number): Observable<any> {
      console.info('person service called');
        return this._http
            .get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

**PeopleComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PeopleService } from './people.service';

@Component({
    template: `
      <h2>
        {{person?.name}} <br>
        <small>{{person?.website}}</small>
      </h2>
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="account" routerLinkActive="active">Account</a> |
        <a routerLink="profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</a>
      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {
    person;

    constructor(
        private _person: PeopleService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPerson();
    }

    getPerson() {
        this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this._person.get(id).subscribe(person => this.person = person);
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Angular, and should be fixed in next release as reported here,

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10814

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10707

```
  import { PeopleModule } from './people/people.module';

  @NgModule({
       imports: [
         ...
         PeopleModule,
         ...
      })
```

Updated your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e4udJy3tSMoSDSxiws0w?p=preview) to not use Lazy loaded module and it works!!

Cheers!!

Comment: Arg! Thanks @Madhu. You've brought me peace of mind.